# Selection doesn't repaint VirtualTreeView

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I have problem with repaint selection on VirtualTreeView node. When I change node text on run time and repaint tree or actual focused node - selection frame is not updated.

Below screen from test app (XE3, VT Version = 5.2.0)

[image: Before change]

[image: After change node text - VirtualTreeView without focus]

[image: After change node text - VirtualTreeView with focus]

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to `RepaintNode, Repaint, Paint` (methods from VirtualTreeView) but without success. 
I know that I can change VT sources but I don't do this if this is not necessary

Below my test app. Thanks!

DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 461
  ClientWidth = 822
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object vt1: TVirtualStringTree
    Left = 296
    Top = 72
    Width = 273
    Height = 217
    Header.AutoSizeIndex = 0
    Header.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Header.Font.Color = clWindowText
    Header.Font.Height = -11
    Header.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Header.Font.Style = []
    Header.MainColumn = -1
    RootNodeCount = 20
    TabOrder = 0
    OnGetText = vt1GetText
    Columns = <>
  end
  object edt1: TEdit
    Left = 336
    Top = 24
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'edt1'
  end
  object btn1: TButton
    Left = 360
    Top = 312
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'btn1'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btn1Click
  end
end
```

PAS:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    vt1: TVirtualStringTree;
    edt1: TEdit;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure vt1GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
      Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

[..]

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vt1.RepaintNode(vt1.GetFirst);
end;

procedure TForm1.vt1GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
begin
  CellText := edt1.Text;
end;
```

Comment: Use `InvalidateNode`.

Comment: @TLama Use "Post Your Answer" ;-)

Comment: Have you tried if updating to the latest version 5.4.1 solves the problem?

Comment: @JoachimMarder No I don't. TLama suggestion helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just so the question can be closed and marked as resolved I'm gonna write @TLama 's comment as answer:

> Use `InvalidateNode`.